# Logback change rolling appender filename location during runtime

Tags: java, logback

I am trying to change the configuration of rollingFileAppender with timebased rolling policy to keeps the logs in different directory.

Here is part of my logback configuration:

```xml
    <appender name="THROUGHPUT_APPENDER" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <prudent>true</prudent>
        <filter class="com.....log.ThroughputLogFilter" />
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>${INFO_LOG_LOCATION}/throughput_%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log</fileNamePattern>
            <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
                <maxFileSize>100MB</maxFileSize>
            </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
            <maxHistory>30</maxHistory>
        </rollingPolicy>
        <encoder>
            <charset>UTF-8</charset>
            <Pattern>%msg%n</Pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
```

And here is my attempt so far to change the file location(Not working):

```java
LoggerContext context = (LoggerContext) LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory();
Map<String, Appender<ILoggingEvent>> appendersMap = new HashMap<>();
for (Logger logger : context.getLoggerList()) {

    Iterator<Appender<ILoggingEvent>> appenderIterator = logger.iteratorForAppenders();
    while (appenderIterator.hasNext()) {
        Appender<ILoggingEvent> appender = appenderIterator.next();

        if (!appendersMap.containsKey(appender.getName())) {
            appendersMap.put(appender.getName(), appender);
            if(appender.getName().equals("THROUGHPUT_APPENDER")){
                System.out.println("==============");
                RollingFileAppender a = (RollingFileAppender)appender;
                TimeBasedRollingPolicy policy = (TimeBasedRollingPolicy)a.getRollingPolicy();
                policy.stop();
                policy.setFileNamePattern("logs/test/throughput_%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log");
                policy.start();
                a.stop();
                a.start();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that in order to work there is a need to change also the RollingFileAppender fileName.

Here is my final approach to change the log directory:

```java
LoggerContext context = (LoggerContext) LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory();
Map<String, Appender<ILoggingEvent>> appendersMap = new HashMap<>();
for (Logger logger : context.getLoggerList()) {

    Iterator<Appender<ILoggingEvent>> appenderIterator = logger.iteratorForAppenders();
    while (appenderIterator.hasNext()) {
        Appender<ILoggingEvent> appender = appenderIterator.next();

        if (!appendersMap.containsKey(appender.getName())) {
            appendersMap.put(appender.getName(), appender);
            if(appender.getName().equals("THROUGHPUT_APPENDER")){
                System.out.println("==============");
                RollingFileAppender a = (RollingFileAppender)appender;
                a.stop();
                a.setFile("some.log");
                TimeBasedRollingPolicy policy = (TimeBasedRollingPolicy)a.getRollingPolicy();
                policy.stop();
                policy.setFileNamePattern("logs/test/throughput_%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log");
                policy.start();
                a.start();
            }
        }
    }
}
```